# Using local fonts on android 4.4 is not working

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-fonts

I'm trying to list all the fonts that are available.Everything seems to work fine on android Oreo ..But When I tested it on my tab it is not working although the android team says that this feature is supported from api 14 and higher...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/size_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

</Spinner>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/amatic_regular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amatic_font"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Amatic"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/annie_use_your_telescope"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/annie_use_your_telescope"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="annie telescope"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Windsong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/windsong"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Windsong"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/cac_champagne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cac_champagne"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cac champangne"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/fff_tsuj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fff_tsuj"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="fff ttsu"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/cavier_dream_font"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cavier_dream_font"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cavier Font"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/roboto_regular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Robboto"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/SEASRN__"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/seasran__"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="seasrn"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Capture_it"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/capture_it"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="capture it"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/OpenSans-Light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OpenSans Light"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RadioGroup>
```

[That's what I get in android Oreo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQXoE.png)

[That's what I get in android kitkat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNZ75.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no clue where you heard that the font resource is supported from Android 4.4 and above, but it's wrong.

`@font` resources weren't added until [Android Oreo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html):

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. You can add the font file in the res/font/ folder to bundle fonts as resources. These fonts are compiled in your R file and are automatically available in Android Studio. You can access the font resources with the help of a new resource type, font. For example, to access a font resource, use @font/myfont, or R.font.myfont.

The `fontFamily` attribute was added earlier, but it's limited by [available fonts](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Fonts) until API 26 where it's released with font resources. In API's below API 26, you have to set custom fonts programmatically.

So for Android Nougat and lower you have to set it programmatically. The `@font` resource is only supported on Oreo and newer.

You can check the current API using something like this: `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)`

Then first load it using this, with your file name of course:

```
Typeface quicksand = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
            "Quicksand-Bold.ttf");
```

and finally, setting it:

```
someTextview.setTypeface(quicksand);
```

You can still keep the attribute in the XML file. XML tags that don't exist on a given API level are simply ignored when built, so you can still keep it around for API 26 and above

## Unless

you use the support library. If you use the support library, commonly known as AppCompat<sub>1</sub>, you can use it. For an instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/myfont-Regular"
          app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Regular"/>
    <font android:fontStyle="italic" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/myfont-Italic"
          app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Italic" />
</font-family>
```

[There's a section in the docs about it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib) that can be nice to read as well.

You also need this dependency (When writing this, the version is the newest. For later usage, you may want to look up the newest version of the support lib):

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
```

<sub>The support libraries are a collection of support dependencies for etc reasons, but the AppCompat library is the support library for backward compatibility, and is the one referenced here</sub>

Comment: "To use the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android API version 14 and higher, use the Support Library 26. For more information on using the support library, refer to the Using the support library section."

Comment: Thank you it worked!!...I'll try to understand what is the support library thing.

Comment: @finchfisher the support library itself is a range of different libraries with the `com.android.support` package. The one you're looking for is AppCompat, added more to the post to describe that